# Как реализовать синтезатор на Python

Tags: python, аудио

Необходимо сделать программу, которая могла бы открывать и проигрывать аудиофайлы, а также возможность изменять эти звуки по нотам (по типу синтезатора). Открытие и воспроизведение смог сделать, а вот изменение по нотам вызвало затруднение т.к не знаю как реализовать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()

    def play(self):
        url = self.url.toString().split('/')
        name = url[-1]

        self.label.setText(name)
        self.player.play()


    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)' )

        self.url = QUrl(self.url)

        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
```

Comment: вы хотите изменять звуки по ходу проигрывания мелодии ? Круто. Может вам для начало стоит создать синтезатор,который будет издавать звуки?

Comment: Возможно следует над этим задуматься. А как это можно реализовать?

Comment: ну например так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203181/%d0%92%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-pyqt5/1203284#1203284

Comment: Спасибо за совет, а после того, как будет реализован синтезатор, будет возможно воплощение моей идеи?

Comment: sorry, я не совсем понимаю вашу задумку, поэтому пока воздержусь от комментариев.

Comment: Суть в том, что выбирается аудиофайл(семпл), и с помощью программы его можно редактировать по тональностям или же по нотам( как это имеется в piano roll в fl studio). Примерно такая идея.